# how to implement custom methods of an ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist

Lets suppose that I have an ArrayList defined as follows:

```
ArrayList<Employee> listWithItems=new ArrayList();
```

I was wondering if there is a way so that I can create a custom method and call it from the ArrayList created. I mean, for example if I create a method for computing the taxes I want to call it like this:

```
listWithItems.computeTaxes();
```

Is there a way to extend the ArrayList in Java to implement custom user methods? I mean if there is like an ArrayList interface that I could use it for those purposes.

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you could extend (subclass) ArrayList.

But that's not a good idea. You should define your own class/interface for your business object. It's all about separation of concerns and having every class do exactly one thing. A generic container (such as ArrayList) should not be dealing with taxes.

You could wrap the ArrayList into your own class, or just have a method that takes the list as a parameter.

```
taxCalculation.computeTaxes(listWithItems);
```

Comment: This is a good example of [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

Comment: Maybe not even composition. The whole container thing could be external to the class if it can do the calculation on individual elements. Of course, if this is like a shopping cart, where the list has a business meaning as well (and is not just a way to pass around multiple entries), then yes, the whole list should be wrapped into a business object class.

Comment: I think you're right. The big thing here is that there's rarely a case where you want to extend an ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interface and wrap inside your new class an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). But don not extend it, as commented by Thilo, is not a good idea.